# List all duplicate values in a nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm wanting to locate all duplicate values in a nested object.
For example I would like the following pets object:

```
var pets = {
  owner1: 'Frank',
  owner2: 'Curly',
  owner3: 'Maurice',
  dogs: {
    terriers: {
      name1: 'Fido',
      name2: 'Woofy',
      name3: {
        goodDog: 'Frank',
        badDog: 'Judas',
      }
    },
    poodles: {
      name1: 'Curly',
      name2: 'Fido',
    },
  },
};
```

to return an array:

```
['Frank', 'Curly', 'Fido']
```

in no particular order. Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you've done to solve this problem so far. StackOverflow is a code-fixing community, not a code-writing community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate and store the keys, then check for duplicates

```js
var pets = {
  owner1: 'Frank',
  owner2: 'Curly',
  owner3: 'Maurice',
  dogs: {
    terriers: {
      name1: 'Fido',
      name2: 'Woofy',
      name3: {
        goodDog: 'Frank',
        badDog: 'Judas',
      }
    },
    poodles: {
      name1: 'Curly',
      name2: 'Fido',
    },
  },
};

var temp  = [];
var dupes = [];

(function iterate(o) {
    for (var key in o) {
     if (typeof o[key] === "object") iterate(o[key]);
        temp.indexOf(o[key]) === -1 ? 
         temp.push(o[key]) : 
         dupes.indexOf(o[key]) === -1 && typeof o[key] === "string" ? 
         dupes.push(o[key]) : o;
    }
})(pets);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dupes) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal works for more then two same values, too.

```js
var pets = { owner1: 'Frank', owner2: 'Curly', owner3: 'Maurice', dogs: { terriers: { name1: 'Fido', name2: 'Woofy', name3: { goodDog: 'Frank', badDog: 'Judas', } }, poodles: { name1: 'Curly', name2: 'Fido', name3: 'Fido', }, }, },
    temp = {},
    dupes = [];

(function iterate(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof o[key] === "object") {
            return iterate(o[key]);
        }
        temp[o[key]] = (temp[o[key]] || 0) + 1;
        temp[o[key]] === 2 && dupes.push(o[key]);

    });
})(pets);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dupes, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```